# i need regular expression for org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE] A UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: java, regex

i want to print only "A UNIQUE constraint failed" this message as output in "org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE]  A UNIQUE constraint failed (UNIQUE constraint failed: Items.Name)" as tack input 
for this type of output ***regular expression*** required.

Answer (score 0):

This just matches a string between `]` and `(` and should be a start.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "\\] (.*) \\(";
final String string = "org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE] A UNIQUE constraint failed (UNIQUE constraint failed: Items.Name)";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve a substring within string which is between two other substrings then you can use the [Quotation constructs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) ( **\\Q** and **\\E** ) within your regular-expression string. This allows you to be quite accurate towards acquiring the substring you really want, for example:

```
// Speculative Exception String:
String inputString = "org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE] A UNIQUE "
                   + "constraint failed (UNIQUE constraint failed: Items.Name)";

String regEx = "\\Q[SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE] \\E(.*?)\\Q(UNIQUE constraint failed\\E";
```

What you place between the Quotation constructs is entirely up to you, it's all a matter of how accurate you want to be with what substring you retrieve especially if you already know what the full input string is going to contain. You are most likely gathering the input string from within an exception **Catch** and you will most likely find that libraries tend to follow a standard exceptions messaging style and therefore there could very well be more than one exception message that contains a substring between a closed square bracket ( **]** ) and a open parenthesis ( **(** ). This of course doesn't really matter though if you ensure the trapped exception string is the one you want to process before passing it through Pattern/Matching. But then again, if that's the case, why bother parsing the exception string at all? Just send back whatever string you like.

Here is a way I might do this:

```
// Speculative Exception String:
String inputString = "org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE] A UNIQUE "
                   + "constraint failed (UNIQUE constraint failed: Items.Name)";

// Remove any Unicode Control Characters from string 
// (should there be any).
inputString = inputString.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");

String regEx = "\\Q[SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE] \\E(.*?)\\Q(UNIQUE constraint failed\\E";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

> **Regular-Expression Explanation:**

[image]

You can play with this expression here at [regular expression 101](https://regex101.com/r/kRW56y/2).